# How do I find documents greater than a certain timestamp?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of JSON objects that all have a timestamp. This is my model:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PriceSchema = new Schema({
  high: {
    type: Number
  },
  last: {
    type: Number
  },
  timestamp: {
    type: Number
  },
  bid: {
    type: Number
  },
  vwap: {
    type: Number
  },
  volume: {
    type: Number
  },
  low: {
    type: Number
  },
  ask: {
    type: Number
  },
  open: {
    type: Number
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Prices', PriceSchema);
```

Now I want to write a method that will search the database for all the entries corresponding to the current day. So I check the current time, and then query everything that is older than yesterday:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  moment = require('moment'),
  Price = mongoose.model('Prices');

exports.list_current_day = function(req, res) {
  var now = moment().valueOf()
  var oneDayAgo = now - 86400000

  Price.findOne({ 'timestamp' > oneDayAgo }, function (err, price) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.json(price)
  })

}
```

But my condition is failing. I get `Unexpected token >`. How do I specify the condition of my search query to return everything with `timestamp > currentDay`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is off. `findOne` takes an object as the first argument describing a property of the target document. The reason you get the error is that a `<` token is invalid inside an object literal and is invalid syntax. Instead, try the following:

```
Price.findOne({
  timestamp: {
    $gt: oneDayAgo
  }
}, function (err, price) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  res.json(price)
});
```

This will use the [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) operator in the query to check if the certain property meets the requirement. Per the MongoDB documentation:

> #### `$gt`
>
> *Syntax*: `{field: {$gt: value} }`
>
> `$gt` selects those documents where the value of the `field` is greater than (i.e. `>`) the specified `value`.

Thus, it will select documents in which the `timestamp` field is greater than `oneDayAgo`.